# Fourth order essentially self adjoint differential operator?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

Can anyone give me a well-motivated example of a symmetric fourth order (or at least higher than three) differential operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, initially defined on Schwartz class that is essentially self-adjoint?

Comment: Did you try $\frac{d^4}{dx^4}$? Maybe some condition like  first, second and third derivatives of elements of the domain go to 0 at infinity.

Comment: Paul's example works as an operator on Schwartz class. It is densely-defined and its closure is selfadjoint, which is what you want. The closure has domain $f\in L^2$ such that $(1+s^2)^2\hat{f}(s) \in L^2$

Comment: Nice! What would the spectrum be?